# InvalidError between Apache and Django, though I can run runserver

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, centos, mod-wsgi

I could solve the problem of the connection between mod_wsgi and apache thanks to Tomas Walch in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947428/wsgi-py-of-myproject-cannot-read-settings-py/34948340#34948340).

However, another error occurs.
I found a question about class Lexer error in [this page](https://github.com/freewizard/SublimeFormatSQL/issues/14).
But I have no idea what to do at all.

```
$ cat /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.859844 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732] mod_wsgi (pid=13563): Target WSGI script '/home/jap/dj/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.859885 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732] mod_wsgi (pid=13563): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/jap/dj/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.859912 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.859934 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/dj/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860007 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860022 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860066 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     django.setup()
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860084 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860125 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860136 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860257 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     app_config.ready()
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860268 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/apps.py", line 15, in ready
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860307 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     dt_settings.patch_all()
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860317 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 227, in patch_all
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860396 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     patch_middleware_classes()
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860408 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 206, in patch_middleware_classes
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860426 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     if not is_toolbar_middleware_installed():
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860436 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 186, in is_toolbar_middleware_installed
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860450 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     from debug_toolbar.middleware import DebugToolbarMiddleware
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860458 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860521 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     from debug_toolbar.toolbar import DebugToolbar
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860532 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/toolbar.py", line 151, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860597 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     urlpatterns = DebugToolbar.get_urls()
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860607 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/toolbar.py", line 145, in get_urls
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860623 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     for panel_class in cls.get_panel_classes():
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860631 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/toolbar.py", line 118, in get_panel_classes
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860648 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     mod = import_module(panel_module)
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860663 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860717 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     __import__(name)
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860728 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860763 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     from debug_toolbar.panels.sql.panel import SQLPanel  # noqa
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860773 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/panel.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860854 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     from debug_toolbar.panels.sql import views
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860864 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/views.py", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860930 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     from debug_toolbar.panels.sql.forms import SQLSelectForm
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860940 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/forms.py", line 13, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.860995 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     from debug_toolbar.panels.sql.utils import reformat_sql
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861009 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861054 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     import sqlparse
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861064 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlparse/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861109 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     from sqlparse import engine
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861118 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlparse/engine/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861167 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     from sqlparse import lexer
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861218 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]   File "/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlparse/lexer.py", line 156
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861224 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]     class Lexer(object, metaclass=LexerMeta):
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861228 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732]                                  ^
[Fri Jan 22 23:49:17.861232 2016] [:error] [pid 13563] [client ::1:57732] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

SyntaxError???
But I can run Django with runserver and can open "http://localhost/myapp/".

```
$ python manage.py runserver
/home/jap/dj/myproject/myapp/views.py:9: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.core.context_processors is deprecated in favor of django.template.context_processors.
  from django.core.context_processors import request

/home/jap/dj/myproject/myapp/views.py:9: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.core.context_processors is deprecated in favor of django.template.context_processors.
  from django.core.context_processors import request

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 22, 2016 - 23:47:47
Django version 1.9.1, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py:45: RemovedInDjango110Warning: The context_instance argument of render_to_string is deprecated.
  using=using)

[22/Jan/2016 23:47:50] "GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9602
[22/Jan/2016 23:47:50] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Jan/2016 23:47:50] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Jan/2016 23:47:50] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/jquery_pre.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Jan/2016 23:47:50] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/jquery_post.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Jan/2016 23:47:50] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Jan/2016 23:47:50] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/img/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Why I cannot open "http://localhost/wsgi/myapp/" with SyntaxError?
Is it a bug or did I do something wrong?
Although, I could run Django with Apache on macOS, El Capitan, before with what I did this time with python2.7.
If someone helps me, I am grateful.

Thank you.

```
$ cat /etc/httpd/conf/django.conf
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /home/jap/dj/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/jap/dj/myproject:/home/jap/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages
<Directory /home/jap/dj/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: You might be using a different version of virtualenv that contains different version of that package. Anyway, it's still a buggy package. Just upgrade it following what the github says.

Comment: Thanks, Shang. Finally I could run Django with mod_wsgi. It took many hours, but I am relieved. It seems I always have hardship with Django. lol Anyway, thank you, Shang.

Comment: just out of curiosity remove the debug toolbar from your project that will narrow down the problem as being a part of that app.

Comment: Ah, really? Debug toolbar might cause the problem? Thank you for your advice.